# Is Script# working with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: script#

I googled around a bit to find an answer but without success.

I am working on the framework for a new project which I develop using Visual Studio 2012 (currently the RC).  I am so excited by Script# that I tried it in VS 2012.  The 'Extensions and Updates' tool provides it, so I thought, cool, just use it...  But all I get is this message when I try to add a new JavaScript item page (or any other Script# item):

[image]

This is the result when I try to add a "jQuery Page Script" item:

[image]

I also tried to reinstall Script# - no success.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is Script# ready for VS 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is pretty strange. One quick question, which presumably you already looked - did the package exist in the location where the vs extension was installed. If not, then that implies VS didn't install the extension correctly in the first place.

However, it looks like the extension got added, at least as far as the templates go.

What seems to be failing is addition of the nuget packages, which happens when you instantiate the project template ... can you try manually adding the ScriptSharp, ScriptSharp.Lib.HTML and ScriptSharp.Lib.jQuery packages, and see if a) that gets you going, and b) is there a problem with nuget package manager that is behind this?

It should definitely work for VS2012.

Comment: Still no luck.  Same result.  When I try to compile, I get the error that 'ScriptSharp.dll', 'System.Xml.dll' and 'System.dll' are not valid script assemblies.  I tried wit .NET 4.0 and .Net 4.5.  At least the 'Package Installation' error is gone.

Comment: Where did System.Xml.dll and System.dll come from? Did you add a regular class from Add New Item, which unfortunately has the bad side-effect of adding references to the project as well? The fact that you're getting that error implies the script# compiler is running, and complaining those aren't script# assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the source of the issue in the following:
1. Create any S# project type
2. Check for the Assembly Reference section in the Solution Explorer for the 'mscorlib', it will be missed.
3. That's why the attribute like GlobalMethods is not found.

I noticed that if you unload the project and then reload (context actions of the Solution Explorer) then the reference is present with proper 'mscorlib' (S# one, from the path where the NuGet package was installed).

I wonder if it is possible to make reference to 'mscorlib' be present in the first case?
Also I noticed that there's no direct reference to 'mscorlib' as it was in previous Project Templates (prior to version 0.7.5.x).

Comment: Upon project creation, the nuget install script runs, which adds an import for the script# target, which adds the build step, as well as the mscorlib reference. The reference itself won't show up in the solution explorer, but its there. The key step here is installation of the nuget package.